# AWS SQS not receiving messages from queue (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have 2 nodejs functions: a timer and a worker. The timer function sends a SQS message to a cue every second containing the date.

The other function is a worker function which polls the queue every 10 seconds.

**I was expecting to receive 10 messages at every poll interval, but this is not happening.**

Timer.js:

```
import { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const SQS = new SQSClient({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "__ACCESS_KEY_ID__",
        secretAccessKey: "__SECRET_ACCESS_KEY__",
    },
    region: "__REGION__",
});

const timer = async () => {
    const input = {
        QueueUrl: "__QUEUE_URL__",
        MessageBody: new Date().toISOString(),
    };

    const command = new SendMessageCommand(input);

    const response = await SQS.send(command);
};

setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

Worker.js:

```
import { SQSClient, ReceiveMessageCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const SQS = new SQSClient({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "__ACCESS_KEY_ID__",
        secretAccessKey: "__SECRET_ACCESS_KEY__",
    },
    region: "__REGION__",
});

const worker = async () => {
    console.log("polling for messages...");

    const input = {
        QueueUrl: "__QUEUE_URL__",
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
    };

    const command = new ReceiveMessageCommand(input);

    const response = await SQS.send(command);

    const { Messages } = response;

    const messagesReceived = Messages
        ? Messages.map((e) => ({
                id: e.MessageId,
                receiptHandle: e.ReceiptHandle,
                body: e.Body,
          }))
        : [];

    if (messagesReceived.length > 0) {
        console.log(messagesReceived.map((e) => e.body));
    }
};

setInterval(worker, 5000);
```

I have tested this with both a standard queue and a fifo queue.

What I want to achieve:

- I want to receive all messages that are send, except for duplicates (so I must go with fifo I think).
- The order is not so important.
- When there are no consumers available, I want the messages to be stored in the queue.

Which settings should I use?

Answer (score 1):

From [ReceiveMessage - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html):

> If the number of messages in the queue is small (fewer than 1,000), you most likely get **fewer messages than you requested** per ReceiveMessage call. If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you **might not receive any messages** in a particular ReceiveMessage response. If this happens, **repeat the request**.

This is due to the distributed architecture of Amazon SQS. See: [Basic Amazon SQS architecture - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html)

I also recommend that you use `WaitTimeSeconds: 20` to reduce the number of `GetMessage()` calls made to the SQS queue when there are no message available.